# how to fix TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in Python

Tags: python

Im gettng this error:

```
f.write("\n"(var13))
```

SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?

For code:

```
if (var11 == "register/"):
     usernamer=input("Username : ")
     var12 = usernamer
     f= open("Username.txt","a+")
     for i in range(1):
             f.write("\n"(var12))
     f.close()
```

Comment: use  `f.write("\n {}".format(var12))`

Comment: Hey @Lakshay, congratulations on your first question! Could you please clarify what you are trying to do and what you're expecting? A bit more context would help others answer your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concatenation of strings works differently.

```
f.write(f"{var12}\n")
```

if you use Python 3.6+ or

```
f.write(var12 + "\n")
```

for earlier versions.

You can also do as follows:

```
if (var11 == "register/"):
     username = input("Username : ")
     with open("Username.txt","a+") as f:
          f.write(f"{usernamer}\n")
```

which makes your code more concise and pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

```
"\n"(var13)
```

This is indeed an attempt to call the "function" `"\n"`, passing `var13` as an argument.

If you want to get the username followed by a newline (the usual situation with `write`), you should use something like, in order of decreasing preference:

```
"{var13}\n"                   # f-string
"{}\n".format(var13)          # old style
"%d\n"%(var13)                # ancient style
```